# open alert dialog activity without opening parent activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm writing a program that offers a quick `AlertDialog`. The `AlertDialog` comes up by itself but the parent activity opens in tasks. 
The app is about receiving SMS. The user runs the app for the first time and closes it, then I start a `Service` and try to read received message using `BroadcastReceiver` and then show an `AlertDialog` anywhere the user is. When I call `AlertDialog`, parent activity starts too. I don't want the parent activity to open on its own.

This is the Android Manifest file:

```
    <activity android:name=".dialog"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme.CustomTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the AlertDialog Box at the beginning (in the onCreate method) of the code in Activity.java class.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Add the AlertDialog Box code here

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
}
```

This will show the dialog before the **Activity** is **initialized**.

Comment: I think I didn't explain enough in the question.

Comment: @ Jatin Bhatia any idea now?